# AngularJS : How do access parent controller's scope item from the child directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My html view as below

**School.html**

```
<html>
<body>
   <div class="col-xs-9">
   <!-- major bootstrap html code goes over here -->
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-3">
       <!--Call to directive goes here--> 
       <div student-profile ngInit="studentId=profileId"></div>
    </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

**Controllers:**
SchoolController.js

```
(function() {

 var app = angular.module("SchoolApp")

 var SchoolController = function ($scope,$rootScope,...)
   {
      $scope.profileId = myData.profileId;
   }
```

studentprofileController.js

```
(function() {

 var app = angular
             .module("SchoolApp")
             .directive('studentProfile',studentProfileDirective)
      function studentProfileDirective(){
      return {  
           restrict :'AE',
           replace:'true',
           controller:studentProfileController,
           bindtocontroller:true,
           template:'student-profile.html'
      } 

studentProfileController.inject=['$scope','$rootScope',...];

function studentProfileController($scope,$rootScope,....)
       {
          var ProfileID = $scope.$parent.profileId;
           console.log("ProfileID",ProfileID);
       }  
   };
```

I have tried $scope.$parent.profileId which is not working. I am getting ProfileID as "undefined". how do i get the parent controller's scope item profileId in the child directive?

Its look like my body controller assign the profileId after my directive gets loaded. So when the first time, my directive loaded, it doesn't get any profileId from its parentscope. How do i do the later sync in that scenario?

Comment: Is the SchollController used in the route definition?

Comment: You have not created any isolated scope with your directive, so both your controller and directive should be sharing the same scope variables. Did you try `var ProfileID = $scope.profileId;`? If that didn't work, can you specify how is your controller structured in the view?

Comment: @NMittal i have tried your suggestion. but no luck. still getting ProfileID undefined message

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe Yes. SchoolController has been used in the route definition. Is that matter for the parent scope accesss?

Comment: Your directive doesn't seem to be creating an isolate scope. The value you're looking for is probably directly on the $scope.

Comment: Its look like my body controller assign the profileId after my directive gets loaded. So when the first time, my directive loaded, it doesn't get any profileId from its parentscope. How do i do the later sync in that scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Move the body controller to the `body` tag.

```
<html>
<body ng-app="SchoolApp" ng-controller="SchoolController">
   <div class="col-xs-9">
   <!-- major bootstrap html code goes over here -->
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-3">
       <!--Call to directive goes here--> 
       <div student-profile ngInit="studentId=profileId"></div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

And be sure to declare it.

```
(function() {

 var app = angular.module("SchoolApp")

 //Be sure to declare it
 app.controller("SchoolController", SchoolController);
 //

 var SchoolController = function ($scope,$rootScope,...)
   {
      $scope.profileId = myData.profileId;
   }
```

By putting the `ng-controller` directive at the top of the `body` hierarchy, the `$compile` service will instantiate it first before compiling the other directives.

Comment: Unfortunately i was wrong. My School.html is a view of a main app. SchoolController is defined in SchoolController.js, SchoolController.js route defined in app.js

Answer (score 0):

When building a custom directive, you control whether it shares the parent scope or creates a child scope. By default, it shares the parent view's scope. If you set `scope: true` on the directive object, it uses a child scope that prototypically inherits from the parent view's scope. If you set `scope: {}` on the directive object, it creates an isolate scope inheriting nothing from the parent view's scope.

So to answer to your question based on how your directive is declared, you access the parent scope with the $scope variable itself since it's shared.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#directives

Comment: Its look like my body controller assign the profileId after my directive gets loaded. So when the first time, my directive loaded, it doesn't get any profileId from its parent scope. How do i do the later sync in that scenario?

Comment: You could use a watcher. `$scope.$watch('profileId', function(){do something});`

Comment: witthout profile id gets a data, i can't load my directive. 
How do i holding my directive from being load till profileId scope variable gets the data?